# I am trying to get count of states with distinct phone numbers and LTV

Tags: mysql, sql

The query i wrote is:

```
SELECT ST,COUNT(PHONE) FROM Consumer.Axciom092013 
WHERE MR_AMT >= (HOME_MKT_VALUE_(.45)) 
and ST = 'TX' or ST = 'CA' or ST = 'AZ' or ST = 'CO' or ST = 'FL';
```

Simply i am trying to find the LTV (Loan-To-Value) ratio of those states, but right now I only need the count of how many records of distinct phone numbers are in each of those states.

I keep getting error about incorrect syntax in line 1.
  I thought i did a step by step for it, but cannot seem to get to work!

I have switched the query around and tried just running `SELECT ST,COUNT(*)`  but then i get an error saying the function `HOME_MKT_VALUE` does not exist

Comment: About that second error, are you sure that function exists (and you spelled it correctly)?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you want this:

```
SELECT ST, COUNT(distinct PHONE)
FROM Consumer.Axciom092013 
WHERE MR_AMT >= HOME_MKT_VALUE_ * 0.45 and
      ST IN ('TX', 'CA', 'AZ', 'CO', 'FL');
```

SQL only does multiplication with an explicit `*`.  Your expression `HOME_MKT_VALUE_(.45)` is the syntax for a function call, not multiplication.

I added the `distinct` for `phone` because you say you want "distinct phone numbers", implying that there could be duplicates on different rows.

EDIT:

By the way, your original query actually has this logic in the `where` clause:

```
WHERE (MR_AMT >= HOME_MKT_VALUE_ * 0.45 and ST = 'TX')
      or ST IN ('CA', 'AZ', 'CO', 'FL');
```

If that is the logic you really do want, then use it instead.

Comment: And you also replaced the ORs with an IN predicate.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT     ST, COUNT(DISTINCT PHONE) 
FROM       Consumer.Axciom092013 
WHERE      MR_AMT >= (HOME_MKT_VALUE_(.45)) 
           and ST IN ('TX', 'CA', 'AZ', 'CO', 'FL')
GROUP BY   ST;                                    //mistaken , PHONE
```

**EDIT:** I did mistake should not be grouped by PHONE.

Comment: If you are getting the COUNT for phone records, why would you group on PHONE?

Comment: @PinnyM See your first answer, you were missing what he wanted. He wanted count of distinct phone numbers. I just wanted to group on phone as well so he can get what he wanted.

Comment: Are you sure this does what you think it does?  Your query would seem to return a single row for each unique ST and PHONE (with a count of how many times that PHONE is duplicated).  It appears that the OP wants a count of DISTINCT phone numbers (count of phone numbers with duplicates removed).

Comment: @PinnyM I am sure, it will group on ST under ST it will group on PHONE.

Comment: @PinnyM I already explained. Can you tell me, what a group on do?

Comment: My reading is the OP wants to *count distinct phone numbers* (`I only need the count of how many records of distinct phone numbers are in each of those states`), not to *count number of instances of every distinct phone number*. Your query seems to find an answer to the latter.

Comment: @AndriyM You are right about my query. There might be misunderstanding that what he wants. "in each of those states", so I grouped by ST and count them.